# How can I convert a nested javascript object into an inline string of CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I have a javascript object that contains descriptions for CSS styles.

This object comes from a third-party API, so I am not able to modify the object.

I'd like to parse and output the object to a string.

The string needs to be useable as a inline styles in the head of my HTML.

I need to be able to map "base" and "invalid" to custom class names.  These can be provided as variables.

The invalid > color needs to be mapped to a border color.  Basically it comes from the object as "color", but I need to use it as a border color.

I've tried nesting loops and have just been extremely stuck trying to figure out an elegant solve to this problem.

Please, if you need more detail, ask me and I'll answer as best I can to help clarify.

The JavaScript Object I receive:

```js
{
    style: {
        base: {
            color: '#46a0ba',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#000'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: 'yellow'
        }
    },
}
```

I need this to output as a sinlge-line string:

(I'm putting this on multiple lines to just make it easier to read here)

```css
.baseClass { color: #46a0ba; }
.baseClass::placeholder {color: #000}
.invalidClass { border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

See CodePen of where I am at so far here:

https://codepen.io/fylzero/pen/gOOvdVp

Comment: Can you post what you got so far in terms of parsing?

Comment: a) is composing a longer string from a bunch of short strings / variables b) is accessing the values in the JS object. Where is the problem exactly? Doing a)? Doing b)? Where are you stuck? There's no parsing necessary at all here.

Comment: @AndreFeijo Here is about where I'm at so far:  https://codepen.io/fylzero/pen/gOOvdVp

Comment: @ChrisG a) I need to convert the object values into the string provided.  b) Yes, the class values are simply passed as const.  I'm stuck on just how to get this converted.  I'm wondering if there isn't n better way than using multiple loops as well.

Comment: Since I don't know how dynamic these API objects are going to be, here's a simple way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2a53sytL/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the response.  It is unfortunately dynamic beyond the base / invalid level, however it will never go deeper than the amount of levels in the example object provided.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the fiddle. It supports arbitrary CSS properties now.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much!  If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.  I really appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm separating the object data into properties that go into the main rule and nested stuff that needs separate rules. Using recursion for the second part and Array functions like `map()` and `join()`, we get:

```js
const inputStyle = {
  base: {
    color: '#46a0ba',
    padding: '0.5em',
    'font-size': '14pt',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#000'
    },
    ':hover': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: 'yellow'
  }
};

function rules(className, obj) {
  const allProps = Object.entries(obj);
  const directProps = allProps.filter(([key, value]) => typeof value == 'string');
  const pseudoProps = allProps.filter(([key, value]) => typeof value == 'object');
  const directStyle = `.${className} { ${directProps.map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value};`).join(' ')} }`;
  const pseudoStyle = pseudoProps.map(([key, value]) => rules(className + key, value)).join(' ');
  return [directStyle, pseudoStyle].join(' ');
}

function appendStyle(baseName, invalidName, styleObj) {
  const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
  styleElement.textContent = [rules(baseName, styleObj.base), `.${invalidName} { border: 1px solid ${styleObj.invalid.color}; }`].join(' ');
  document.head.append(styleElement);
}

appendStyle("baseClass", "invalidClass", inputStyle);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input class="baseClass" placeholder="placeholder">
<input class="baseClass invalidClass" value="hello">
```